# C# Отмена асинхронного метода блокирует изменение полей

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

Использую WPF, MVVM паттерн. На ряду с использованием метода `Webclient.DownloadFileTaskAsync()` отдельным методом вынес и `WebClient.CancelAsync()`, который тригерится нажатием кнопки. В том же метода идет передача вместе с изменением поля `Label` в форме. Получилось так:

```
            CancelDownloading = new DelegateCommand(() =>
            {
               MessageProgress = "Скачивание отмененно"; //Передача состояния в Label
               _downloader.CancelDownload(); //Отмена асинхронной операции
            });
```

И все ничего, но при тригере этого метода с помощью Button происходит только остановка загрузки. При повторном только нажатии изменяется поле Label. Поле, в которое передается MessageProgress обернуто в свойство:

```
    private string messageProgress;

    public string MessageProgress
    {
        get { return messageProgress; }
        set { SetProperty(ref messageProgress, value); }
    }
```

Почему изменение происходит только после повторного нажатия Button?

**Update**

Изначально упустил момент, что MessageProgress принимает значения из другого метода, который передает значение `Webclient.DownloadProgressChange`. Тем не менее, в дебагере видно, что значение изменено, но в UI значение не обновилось, только остановился процесс загрузки (`ProgressBar` в том числе).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь класс Downloader, отмена идет метода DownloadAllFiles

```
class Downloader:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
#region INPC progress
    private int _progress;
    public int counter = 1;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public int Progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _progress)
            {
                _progress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Progress");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    public async Task DownloadAllFiles(Dictionary<string, bool> context, string pathFile)
    {
        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += Download_Changing;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> pair in context)
        {
            string result = pair.Key.Substring(pair.Key.IndexOf("src/") + 14);
            string fileName = pathFile + @"\" + result;

            await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(pair.Key, fileName);
            counter++;
        }
        wc.Dispose();
    }

    private void Download_Changing(object s, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgrChanged(this, new ProgressEventArgs(e.ProgressPercentage));
    }

    public void CancelDownload()
    {
        wc.CancelAsync();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> ProgrChanged;
}
```

Comment: `WebClient.CancelAsync()` покажите код, где вы это вызываете

Comment: @tym32167  public void CancelDownload() { wc.CancelAsync(); }

Comment: Думаю там проблема с конфигурацией контекста.

Comment: весь код добавляйте в вопрос. И покажите, как вы биндите сообщение на label

Comment: @tym32167 могу дать ссылку на гит хаб, если Вас не затруднит

Comment: Понятно, а теперь приложите текстом ваш класс `Downloader`, оттуда и будет видно что не так. Я подозреваю что у вас нарушение контекста выполнения происходит.

Comment: @LLENN добавил в тело вопроса